# .htaccess not redirecting after uploading

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

On a website I'm working, on localhost all the links were working fine through. But after uploaded my files on a host, the website remains stuck on the home page. this is my htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^produse/?$ index.php?page=produse
RewriteRule ^product/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=product&id=$1
RewriteRule ^product_type/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=product_type&id=$1
RewriteRule ^mind/?$ index.php?page=mind
RewriteRule ^register/?$ index.php?page=register
RewriteRule ^register/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=register&err=$1
RewriteRule ^furnizori/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=furnizori&id=$1
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?page=contact
RewriteRule ^contact/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=contact&err=$1
RewriteRule ^servicii/?$ index.php?page=servicii
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?page=login
RewriteRule ^login/([^/]*)?$ index.php?page=login&err=$1
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ logout.php
RewriteRule ^desprenoi/?$ index.php?page=desprenoi
RewriteRule ^show_submenu_products/?$ index.php?page=show_submenu_products
```

Comment: Did you send the file in text mode ? (Many FTP programs send .htaccess files in binary mode, and that can be a problem...)

Comment: It wasn't that, but now it works. It seems that in preview menu on the host, .htaccess doesn't work. But when the website is on, everything is ok. Thank you for your answer!